# How do I get my windows (UK Layout) keyboard to work on Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard

How do I get my windows keyboard to work on my Mac? I want to be able to bind the keys so it's like I'm using a windows computer, i.e. ctrl maps to command, but I've tried everything to no avail. Also, how would I map the symbols to the correct places, for instance \ is where ` should be, etc.

Answer (score 5):

- To change the modifier keys, go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard and choose Modifier Keys….

  [image]
- To map the keys to the correct places, go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Input Sources, click the **+** and choose British PC.
- To ensure that your keyboard is identified correctly, go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Change Keyboard Type and follow the instructions to allow OS X to identify the keyboard.

Comment: Hey, I've done those; what do I map the modifier keys to? And also, the british PC thing doesn't work for some symbols

Comment: @Jeehan Set them to your preferences for the modifier keys, it's up to how you want your keyboard layout set up. The British PC setup should work for all keys.

Comment: I'm kind of new to to the whole Mac layout so what would the corresponding keys be?

Comment: @JeehanJan  What symbols are not right when you have British PC choosen for your keyboard layout?  It is supposed to match the standard Windows keyboard.  But here are some other ones  http://liyang.hu/osx-british.xhtml

Comment: @TomGewecke For instance on the keyboard it shows a backslash in the bottom left corner, but when I press it I get a `, and it should print a pipe on shift press, but instead I get a ¬

Comment: Try British PC105 from the liyang site.

Comment: @TomGewecke I'll give it a go, thanks :) Edit: I tried the PC105 Alt one and it appeared to work. Do you have any ideas about the modifier settings?

Comment: Not sure, I think you may map Control to Command and Command to Control?  The Windows key is Command?.

Answer (score 2):

You can visualise how your windows keyboard is configured by showing the 'Keyboard Viewer'

[image]
[image]

```
System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Enable 'Show Keyboard, Emoji & Symbol Viewers in menu bar' -> go on menu bar -> click on the new icon -> Show Keyboard Viewer
```

And after that, you can reMap your keys with this really great soft :

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

By this way, you can easily revert your ReyMap to use the native Keyboard when you want.